# Finite difference method for non-linear PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, transport-equation

I'm trying to numerically solve the following fairly simple non-linear PDE:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial t}=-V_g(\omega)\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial z}
\end{equation}

I've discretised this as follows:

\begin{align}
\frac{\omega(z,t+\Delta t) - \omega(z,t)}{\Delta t} &= -V_g(\omega(z,t))\frac{\omega(z+\Delta z,t) - \omega(z-\Delta z,t)}{2\Delta z}\\
\omega(z,t+\Delta t) &=\omega(z,t)-\Delta t V_g(\omega(z,t))\frac{\omega(z+\Delta z,t) - \omega(z-\Delta z,t)}{2\Delta z}
\end{align}

which is simple enough. However I've managed to derail myself when it comes to the boundary conditions. The initial conditions are essentially the delta function:

\begin{equation}
\omega(z,0) = \delta(z)
\end{equation}

This is where I come unstuck. With everything as written above, the system won't evolve, because $V_g(\omega)$ is, based on these boundary conditions, zero everywhere except $z=0$, and so no evolution occurs. I'm fairly sure the issue is with how I'm handling $V_g(\omega)$, but for the life of me I can't figure out what the solution is.

Comment: Can you write how $V_g (\omega)$ is expressed?

Comment: You should try just replacing the centred difference with an upwind difference based on the sign of $V_g$.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation $\partial_t\omega + V_g(\omega)\partial_z\omega = 0$ is a first-order quasilinear PDE. This nonlinear transport equation carries information at the characteristic speed $V_g(\omega)$. Let us consider a regular grid with uniform mesh size $\Delta z = z_{i+1} -z_{i}$, and variable time step $\Delta t = t_{n+1} -t_{n}$. We write $\omega_i^n \simeq \omega(z_i, t_n)$. The finite-difference scheme
$$
\frac{\omega_i^{n+1}-\omega_i^n}{\Delta t} = V_g (\omega_i^n) \frac{\omega_{i+1}^n-\omega_{i-1}^n}{2\Delta x}
$$
written in OP is unstable (see e.g. [[1]](https://books.google.fr/books?id=3WhqLPcMdPsC&lpg=PA216&ots=NTtbuhebYL&dq=leveque%201992%20birkhauser&hl=fr&pg=PA216#v=onepage&q&f=false)). The small modification
$$
\frac{\omega_i^{n+1}-\frac{1}{2}(\omega_{i-1}^n+\omega_{i+1}^n)}{\Delta t} = V_g (\omega_i^n) \frac{\omega_{i+1}^n-\omega_{i-1}^n}{2\Delta x}
$$
makes it conditionally stable. This is the non-conservative Lax-Friedrichs method, stable under the Courant-Friedrichs-Lewy (CFL) condition  $\max_i V_g (\omega_i^n)\frac {\Delta t}{\Delta x} < 1$. Viewed as a finite-volume method, one should initialize the data to the cell-averages of $\omega (z,0)=\delta (z)$, i.e.
$\omega_i^{0} = \delta_i^{0}/\Delta z$,
where $\delta_i^{0}$ is the Kronecker delta.

An alternative consists in writing the nonlinear transport equation above in conservative form. If we define the flux $F_g(\omega) = \int^\omega V_g(\nu)\, \text{d}\nu$ as an antiderivative of $V_g$, then the transport equation rewrites as a conservation law:
$\partial_t\omega + \partial_z F_g(\omega) = 0$. Thus, one can implement straightforwardly finite-volume methods such as the conservative [Lax-Friedrichs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lax%E2%80%93Friedrichs_method) method
$$
\frac{\omega_i^{n+1}-\frac{1}{2}(\omega_{i-1}^n+\omega_{i+1}^n)}{\Delta t} = \frac{F_g (\omega_{i+1}^n)-F_g (\omega_{i-1}^n)}{2\Delta x} .
$$

---

[[1]](https://books.google.fr/books?id=3WhqLPcMdPsC&lpg=PA216&ots=NTtbuhebYL&dq=leveque%201992%20birkhauser&hl=fr&pg=PA216#v=onepage&q&f=false) R.J. LeVeque, *Numerical Methods for Conservation Laws*, Birkhäuser, 1992.

Comment: Don't we have a dimensional problem here? If $z$ has units of length and $t$ has units of time, then $V_g(\omega)$ will have the units of speed. Why is $V_g'(\omega)$ the propagation speed? In general that will have the wrong units. Also, consider the case where $V_g(\omega)$ is a constant. Then $V_g'(\omega) = 0$ and your stability condition would imply that this is *always* stable, which it isn't. I think the form of this problem is slightly different than the standard nonlinear form assumed in the Lax-Friedrichs Wikipedia link.

Comment: Also: Shouldn't the initial condition be $\omega_i^0 = \delta_i^0 / \Delta x$?

Comment: @JohnBarber Thank you very much for your comments. There were 2 mistakes in my answer which you noticed. Answer updated! The fact is that OP gives the non conservative equation. Therefore, one must use non conservative methods, or transform into conservative form.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I feel I may be a little out of my depth, but I'll try what you've suggested and see how I go.